# Let shell/terminal paste by replacing newline with space

Tags: terminal, string, clipboard

How do I paste into a shell or terminal and simultaneously replace every newline with a space?

Comment: Run `tr '\n' ' '` and paste into it?

Comment: What is your shell? Maybe your looking for Bash's bracketed paste.